# How to return list of object which associated with one ID?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am still getting familiar with SQL and LINQ and I am trying to get every objects and its objects which is under one ID.

The below is the EDMX Diagram.

[image]

I am passing ClientID and I want to list everything that is under that ClientID and the below is my query to do so but as you can see query is only returning the first element but how to change it to return the list of every elements as below:

Passed ClientID

- THeaderTitle 1
- TReportName 1
- TReportName 2

MY query is below which is returning the first element:

```
  public TReportHeaderModel GetHeadersByClient(int ClientID)
    {

        using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
            {

            var query = (from c in connection.THeader.Include("TReports")

                         where
                         c.ClientID == ClientID
                         select new TReportHeaderModel()
                         {
                             ID = c.ID,
                             THeaderTitle = c.THeaderTitle,
                             RowNumber = c.RowNumber,
                             TReports = (from t in c.TReports
                                         select new TReportModel()
                                         {
                                             ID = t.ID,
                                             TReportName = t.TReportName,
                                             URL = t.URL,
                                             RowNumber = t.RowNumber



                                         }).ToList()

                         }).First();



            return query;

        }
    }
```

I've got it working!

I had to change it in my interface as

IList GetHeadersByClient (int ClientID);

So that I can return List of elements in my controller to pass to view.

```
public IList<TReportHeaderModel> GetHeadersByClient(int ClientID)
        {

            using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
                {

                var query = (from c in connection.THeader.Include("TReports")

                             where
                             c.ClientID == ClientID
                             select new TReportHeaderModel()
                             {
                                 ID = c.ID,
                                 THeaderTitle = c.THeaderTitle,
                                 RowNumber = c.RowNumber,
                                 TReports = (from t in c.TReports
                                             select new TReportModel()
                                             {
                                                 ID = t.ID,
                                                 TReportName = t.TReportName,
                                                 URL = t.URL,
                                                 RowNumber = t.RowNumber



                                             }).ToList()

                             });



                return query.ToList();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I did try changing it to ToList(). However, then I when I return 'query'. I will get an error message saying 'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.LIST to regular model. '

Comment: Are you trying to pull all `TReports` for a client but it is only pulling one?

Comment: yes, I am trying to all TReports and THeader for a client but it is only giving me the first element.

Comment: @GerleBatde Your'e getting that error because you method is still declared to return a single `ReportHeaderModel`, and not a `List<TReportHeaderModel>`

Comment: @SamIam I did but I am getting error message when I return query saying cannot implicilty convert Ilist to Model

Comment: @GerleBatde That is because your VIEW wants a precise model format, you also need to change that. Once we are here, what does your view look like ? This looks like you are trying to learn MVC and LINQ at same time

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I've got it! There is nothing wrong with learning it all at the same time, huh?

Comment: Can you please show the output you are getting

Comment: It should be working now as you changed it to return a list. Do you still have any problems?

Comment: @GerleBatde No nothing wrong as you say, it's just harder for us to answer. But i'm no better, i asked some questions likes these too.

Comment: @Coding It is working as I wanted it to now. Now I know the difference between returning single element to list of elements. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Very true! Thanks so much for your time. Now I know the difference between returning list of items and single items. Helped me a lot to understand while trying it out. Again, thanks!